# Websocket Cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, websocket

I'm just new to websocket, I don't know how to access to these cookie in websocket request header. It doesn't have domain or path. Is there any way to use javascript to read or re-rewrite these cookie?

[This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO4Qo.png)

Comment: The information you have provided is pretty thin to tell what you're really asking.  Are your trying to create a cookie or read a cookie?  Are you trying to do it on the client or on the server?   If on the server, are you trying to do it when the client first connects or later on when you receive a webSocket message?

Comment: this cookie is on client, the server is using NodeJS, and it send Set-Cookie to client. After I update the code on server, the test cookie on client still there, I want to delete or edit this cookie so I could able to test the code but I don't know where to find it.

Comment: You will have to show us all relevant code for us to know how to help you.  You need to make this a question about your specific code, not a theoretical question.  Questions here about your code must include your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Websocket request looks like HTTP, but it's not.
So, cookie header is not available.
As a workaround, you may send cookie after a handshake.
Something like:

```
var ws = new Websocket(...);
ws.onopen = function(e) {
    ws.send(document.cookie);
}
```

And pick up the cookie on server side.